# How to add drawer in every activity android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-drawer

I am new to android programming. i want to add drawer view in every activity.
i have tried a lot to add drawer in every activity by extending main activity. but it's getting crash.

please someone guide me how to add drawer in all activity from scratch.below i added my `HomeActivity`

**HomeActivity.java**

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements 
             NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    protected DrawerLayout drawer;

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


             drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);



    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        return false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a [single-activity app](https://medium.com/rosberryapps/a-single-activity-android-application-why-not-fa2a5458a099), which means using `fragments`instead of activities. Then you can easily create a drawer in your `MainActivity` and start fragments from there.

For more information about fragments look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

And how to add an [drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743401/add-navigation-drawer-to-an-existing-activity) to an existing activity.